# Filter repetitive inotify events about the same file in C

Tags: c, filtering, inotify

I'm developing a basic dropbox program. Very simple. I'm kinda stuck with the inotify thing. I need events that notifies about file creation, modification and deletion. I also need to filter out temporary files. I assume I need to be careful to not filter out truthful events, like if a user modifies the same file two or more times in a row.

If a modify a simple text file, I get three separate events: *IN_CLOSE_WRITE test.c*, *IN_MOVED_TO test.c* and *IN_CLOSE_WRITE test.c*. My expected result would be a single notify event about this file. Either one it's fine. All of them sends the same signal to server, to upload the file.

If I copy a file 'test.c': *IN_CREATE test (copy).c* and *IN_CLOSE_WRITE test (copy).c*. See the example above for the expected result.

Here's my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EVENT_BUF_LEN 4096
#define EVENT_SIZE sizeof(struct inotify_event)

typedef struct
{
  int length, fd, wd;
  char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN] __attribute__((aligned(__alignof__(struct inotify_event))));
} notification;

notification inotify;

void getNotified(char *pathname)
{
  char command[256];
  notification inotify;

  inotify.fd = inotify_init();
  inotify.wd = inotify_add_watch(inotify.fd, pathname, IN_CLOSE_WRITE | IN_CREATE | IN_MOVED_TO | IN_MOVED_FROM);

  while (1)
  {
    inotify.length = read(inotify.fd, inotify.buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN);
    int i = 0;

    while (i < inotify.length)
    {
      struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&inotify.buffer[i];
      // Filtering out temporary files.
      if (strstr(event->name, ".gout") != NULL)
      {
        i += (EVENT_SIZE + event->len);
        continue;
      }

      if (event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
        strcpy(command, "IN_CLOSE_WRITE ");

      else if (event->mask & IN_CREATE)
        strcpy(command, "IN_CREATE ");

      else if (event->mask & IN_MOVED_FROM)
        strcpy(command, "IN_MOVED_FROM ");

      else if (event->mask & IN_MOVED_TO)
        strcpy(command, "IN_MOVED_TO ");

      strcat(command, event->name);
      printf("%s\n", command);

      i += (EVENT_SIZE + event->len);
    }
  }

  inotify_rm_watch(inotify.fd, inotify.wd);
  close(inotify.fd);
}

int main(void)
{
  getNotified(".");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect this might be a feature of what your editor is doing. If I just modify a file like `echo hi > foo` I just get a single event (close_write). But if I edit it, say with vi, I get all sorts of events (and temp files).

Comment: @pmacfarlane Yeah, I just don't know what to do. Maybe the professor won't mind. I'm using an editor called xed on Linux Mint. But the laboratory PCs uses Ubuntu.

Comment: I guess it depends on what exactly you've been asked to do. If there are specific types of temp files you've been asked to ignore, I guess you'll need to filter based on filenames of that form. Or maybe you want to make a queue of files that need to be processed, but only process them after N seconds have passed. Multiple events on the same file only generate a single queue entry.

Comment: @pmacfarlane But that if (strcmp(event->name, ".gout")) can't handle that case? It seems I'm not getting events related to temp files, but rather different events about the same file.

Comment: I tried editing a file with `xedit`, which I'm assuming may be the same as, or related to, the `xed` you mention. When you save an edit to file `foo`, it renames the existing file to `foo~` then creates a new file `foo` with the new contents. This doesn't seem unreasonable - it is maintaining a backup of the previous version. Maybe you need to detect moved_from/moved_to pairs and realise that they are renames.